# recv blocking until second packet is sent

Tags: c, tcp, windows-ce, recv

I'm using the `recv` method to receive data over TCP on a Windows CE 6.1 system. For some reason, the first call to recv sometimes blocks until the next packet is sent. I now suddenly get both packets at once.

```
tcpClientSocketId = accept( tcpServerSocketId, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (int *)&sockaddrLength );
if( tcpClientSocketId < 0) return;
recvCount = recv( tcpClientSocketId, buffer, TCP_RECV_BUFFERSIZE, 0 );   //blocking until second packet is received
```

I verified that the data is actually sent using Wireshark. Does anybody have an idea why the `recv` method blocks?

Edit:
Just to clarify: I'm not relying on the data being received packet by packet - these are combined to a string and later processed.
I don't know how I could verify that the data is actually received in the Windows CE system except for waiting for the recv call to return, but I could see that the data was sent using wireshark on the client side, and the data of both packets is received at once as soon as a second packet is sent. If I do not send the second packet, the recv call blocks forever.

Comment: Expecting a TCP connection to respect packet boundaries is fundamentally wrong.  TCP connections are *streams*.  Given that, though, what you have described does seem somewhat strange.  Have you verified that the packet is actually received? Have you tested how long the `recv()` blocks after the first packet has been received?

Comment: You protocol will need to encapsulate some means of identifying message boundaries. Typically, these fall into one of two categories: Length prefix (e.g. HTTP's Content-Length header and chunked encoding, Pascal strings), and sentinel values (e.g. FTP's newline-terminated commands and responses, C's NUL-terminated strings).

Comment: At least from the code you show `recv()` does not read from the socket returned by `accept()`.

Comment: This was only a typing error (I removed the `pT->` everywhere else, but forgot it there)

Answer (score 1):

When using a stream-based socket you have no guarantee about how data will be processed, all a completed recv call tells you is that some amount of data arrived or that the remote end has disconnected its send side and all data has arrived or that there was an error. Even if all data is sent as a single wire packet a single recv may not get all of it, even if the provided buffer is large enough. TCP does, however, guarantee delivery order. You need some other method of determining that a complete communication has been received (end-of-line is an often chosen trigger for text-based protocols).

Comment: Please see my edit: I do not rely on the data being received as packets. My problem is that I do not receive any data until a second packet is sent, although a first (non-empty) packet was actually sent.